# Good resource for web3 developer

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

I'm new to Web3, basically just started by yesterday. As a new web3 developer, I'm finding really hard to start. The document from Ethereum or any are not easy to follow. I wonder do you have any good sources/services to start working with Web3. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe each person have their own style of studying new thing. For my experience here are some good resources and learning path that you can follow:

1. First, you need to understand the basic of BC first, before going into coding. These are the things you should know and its source for refer:

- Public-key Cryptography: https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-public-key-cryptography
- Digital Signature: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptography_digital_signatures.htm
- Hashing: https://learn.bybit.com/blockchain/what-is-hashing-in-blockchain/

2. Then, after you have the basic, it good to start understanding bitcoin and ethereum blockchain. These are some good sources to follow

- Blockchain: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blockchain.asp
- Bitcoin: https://michaelnielsen.org/ddi/how-the-bitcoin-protocol-actually-works/
- Ethereum: https://preethikasireddy.medium.com/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369

3. At this step, you may have a good imagination of how blockchain works. Its time to code. Depend on each person, they have different style of coding. I suggest to try coding by playing. Cryptozombie (https://cryptozombies.io/) is a good game, providing interacting coding section, that helps you to code Solidity in an entertainment way for free.
   Also, this game are refered to me a lot (https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/) but I do not have time to try.
4. Now, after you know basic step-by-step for a smart contract development. It is good time for real-problem. Learning by doing is always true. You can pick one or two projects that can easily find in github or youtube to follow.
5. Then, with solid background of SC development, you can challenge yourself with advanced topic, such as Token Standards (ERC-165, ERC-xxx) and Ethereum virtual machine code based.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the detailed answer. It definitely helps me during my learning path.